# nginx passenger doesnt care about 'passenger_app_env', always runs as production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, passenger

I'm setting up a staging server on EC2, installed nginx+passenger for a rails 3.2+ application. However passenger insists on running it as a production server, despite being told **twice** that the `rails_env` is `staging`.

I can clearly see that from nginx's `error.log` which shows passenger couldn`t reach production database.

This is my `nginx.conf`, well, part of it:

```
http {
  passenger_root /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/passenger-4.0.43;
  passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1;
  passenger_app_env staging;

  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name staging.coke-imc.com;
    root /home/ubuntu/imc-staging/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_env staging;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   html;
    }
  }
}
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to my mind is that you somehow override those environment variables on the application level. Maybe you use `dotenv` and you load up `RAILS_ENV` variable there as well, and maybe - just maybe, it's `production`? :)

Comment: Yes this is probably the issue. A while ago we (Phusion) received a similar support request from a customer. Turns out one of this developers had hardcoded RAILS_ENV inside application.rb.

Comment: My dotenv was set for "staging", but that wouldn't matter – as far as I know – dotenv is being loaded to Rails app, not shell, which means a nginx / passenger wouldn't know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092225/how-to-use-different-rails-env-with-nginx-passenger-and-redmine/22734909#22734909), it may be because you're using the same path for your development, staging and production environments.

Comment: I only have one environment on this server. Production is on a completely, physically different one.

Comment: Aside from the other answer, the only thing I can think of is that you originally booted in production mode, but then changed nginx config to staging but didn't restart the server (or specifically passenger). The running process will never change its environment, so you have to restart completely.