# Can't make passenger (for rails) running my apps in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

First of all: the versions!
Rails 4
Passenger: don't know but the last one that I directly compiled on the server.
Nginx: last one also.

So, my problem is:
I am trying to make a rails app running in production with nginx and passenger but I did not succeed until now. It remains being in development mode.

We are told in the doc of passenger that the default mode is "production" but passenger keep telling me that the running mode is "development" when I comment the section "development" in the conf file /app/config/databases.yml.

I tried to define the env var rails_env, passenger_app_env, rack_env, wsmi_env (or sth like that), node_env in the .bash_profile file of the user launching passenger.

No changes.

I added "rails_env production; passenger_app_env production;" in the nginx conf file but it does not help.

Anybody can help?

Thanks a lot for reading. ;)

---

**EDIT 1:**
I am still getting the following error:

```
'development' database is not configured. Available: ["abc", "production"] (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

Even if the debug info tells:

```
Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and PASSENGER_APP_ENV):
    development
```

And if I check my env vars, I get it:

```
$ env | grep pro
RACK_ENV=production
WSGI_ENV=production
NODE_ENV=production
RAILS_ENV=production
PASSENGER_APP_ENV=production
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you ran "bundle install --deployment"?

Comment: Did you restarted/reloaded nginx after change nginx.conf file?

Comment: @ japed: I ran "bundle install". Not enough?
I'm still a begininer in rails configuration.

@ maxd: Yep, I did.

Comment: May be you have [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092225/how-to-use-different-rails-env-with-nginx-passenger-and-redmine/22734909#22734909) problem.

Comment: Thanks @maxd . I am trying to run only one app so there can't be conflict between different running mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally found out what was wrong.

I launched the rails app with the passenger start command in the file /etc/rc.local but my environment vars was not loaded yet so passenger did run in development mode...

Thanks everybody.