# Nginx server_name regex match not setting passenger_app_env

Tags: nginx, passenger

Nginx: Built with `passenger-install-nignx-module`

Passenger Version: 5.0.28

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

---

I have symlinked each of my apps into their own set of environment folders:

- /Repository

  - /development.manager

    - /app
    - ...
  - /test.manager
  - /staging.manager
  - ...

Where the actual folders is at another location on my HDD. All of these folders are symlinks pointing to that one folder.

The problem is that Nginx doesn't seem to be setting the passenger environment variable properly. Checking the logs it throws an app error that doesn't make sense (and the nginx config is the only thing that's changed since things broke). Also, the error page showing states:

> Because you are running this web application in staging or production
>   mode, the details of the error have been omitted from this web page
>   for security reasons.

Which means that it's not using the development environment even though the `root` directory in the logs shows `development.manager`. This is when I access through the url: `http://manager-development/`.

Here's the relevant excerpt from my nginx `sites-enabled` configuration:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name ~^manager-(?<environment>development|test)$;
  passenger_app_env $environment;
  passenger_ruby /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@manager/wrappers/ruby;
  passenger_enabled on;
  root /home/vagrant/apps/$environment.manager/public;
  client_max_body_size 30M;
}
```

I have a feeling the solution might be a combination of an answer I provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092225/how-to-use-different-rails-env-with-nginx-passenger-and-redmine/22734909?s=2%7C2.2704#22734909) as well as a possibly misconfigured nginx block.

EDIT: I explicitly raised an error in my rails app that output the environment as a string and it's literally "$environment"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've given up on this approach as it seems variables aren't interpreted by nginx when used in certain places. I'm now using a custom Bash/Ruby script to iterate over my environments/app names and generate the configuration blocks.